# Set Background image, if the Custom Listview item is pressed

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using custom list view using base adapter

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="#3d4241"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listbackground">
    </ListView>
```

and listbackground.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

when i click on item the image background is just flashing but i want it should be activated 
and show the background.
i used `android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator` in custom listview but it does not work for api below level 11.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake i will edit my new answer it will work correctly try this one....

Comment: I edited my new answer check it out..? Now

Comment: Now again i changed my code use this you can get the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use this custom adapter in you listview

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;
public int[] i ;
public int start=0;
private LinearLayout layout;
private View view;
private View mLastView;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    start=0;
    this.context = context;
    i = new int[this.mlist.size()];
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutSample);;
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());      
    layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            if(start==0)
            {
                mLastView = v;
                start++;
            }

            if(start>0)
            {
                mLastView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                mLastView = v;
            }

            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);               
        }
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: no it is not working and one more thing i am using public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter.

Comment: I think you are like as a gmail view is in it...?

Comment: i used this view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // you just put your Logic here And use this custom adapter to
            // load your Data By using this particular custom adapter to
            // your listview
            view.setBackgroundResource(Color.GRAY);
        }
    });

Comment: Ya definitely it will loose his background when you scrooling down because of the getview concurrent calling...So you just mainatin the clicked position..that's all

Comment: i used this `view.setOnClickListener` as you suggested but now background is set to the last item if any of the item and click is not working

Comment: ya it's working but if i select another item it should not removing previously selected item

Comment: ya it is working but one more problem it is not performing the task when clicked on the item

Comment: You just write the per-formation inside the onclick that's all

Comment: previously it was working now when i added your code it is now just setting the background to the selected item it is not performing on click task can u help

Comment: Ya you just write your logic inside my onclick function in the custom adapter that's all

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listselector, you can try this:

Create bg_key.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
       android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
  </selector>
```

Then include this background to your listview:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
```

And then, in your activity, create an onclick listner for your listview:

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
      view.setSelected(true);

  }
}
```

The color code in bg_key, is up to you..

Comment: No i tried that it will not work. and as i mentioned i am using custom listview if i use in my custom design layout background `android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator` this will work only for api level 11 or above but i want in api level 8 and above

Answer (score 0):

you could try this with the previous version of your code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:state_selected="false"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background" android:state_pressed="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background" android:state_selected="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_background" android:state_active="true"/>
</selector>
```

Then in the onClick of the view, get the relativeLayout or the LinearLayout inflating the row, and set its activated and also selected property to true, and that way i think you will get a background that remains.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No for this you written "Then in the onClick of the view, get the relativeLayout or the LinearLayout inflating the row, and set its activated and also selected property to true, and that way i think you will get a background that remains."