# Android Listview set background for selected position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am having `ListView` in my application where i have code to set background on the selected item now that code is working properly in android version 3.0 above when i run same application in below 3.0 (that is in 2.3.3) it is not setting the background to the selected item but it is setting the background to the other item in the `ListView` like if i click on the first item of `ListView` it is setting background to the last item if i click on second item then it is setting background to the second last item and so on, only when it come to the centre item is setting background correctly for selected item.

CustomlistAdapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_hadapter, null);

    TextView txtDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtdate); 


    HashMap<String, String> listPurchaseHistory = new HashMap<String, String>();
    listPurchaseHistory = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    txtDate.setText(listPurchaseHistory.get(PurchaseHistory.strTagDate));

    return vi;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
  View selectedRow;
 lstPurchaseOption.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if (selectedRow != null) {
                selectedRow.setBackgroundResource(color.transparent);
            }
            selectedRow = view;
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? used list View Selector instead

Comment: i have custom listview and i tried many thing to setbackground image for selected item this was my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728444/set-background-image-if-the-custom-listview-item-is-pressed it works but setonItemclickListner was not working so i did this one the above code will work fine in 3.0 or above version but not lesser version

Comment: wait for a while i'll check it

Comment: ListView is a sequence of views (list items), so once you know the position, you'd be able to access the corresponding item view and set its background. You're supposed to reset all item views prior to setting any item view

Comment: @mangusta position is properly working but only the background is not setting for the selected view.

Comment: @Wizard could you show your full `onItemClickListener` ? if it uses variables from outside, then it would be better if you show the code of your Activity altogether

Comment: @mangusta what type of variable

Comment: @SimplePlan what happen did u tried this

Answer (score 0):

I have done it once using getView method in ListView adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu_item, parent, false);

    ...

    if(position == selectedValue){
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_menu_item);
    }
    else{
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.inactive_menu_item);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

and then in your `onItemClickListner`:

```
mainMenuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {...
    mainMenulistAdapter.setSelectedValue(position);
    //redraws the list and sets backgrounds to elements
    mainMenulistAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
```

Comment: it is the position of item which is clicked and which has changed background. it is an integer in list adapter. at the begining you can set it to -1 to indicate that no list item is selected.

Comment: ok but how the values is set to the variable `selectedValue` it will be always -1

Comment: it is set after click on each element in the second fragment of code I provided. you set onItemClick to the list and then in this method you change it by setSelectedValue(position) (you have to write a setter for selectedValue in adapter). (you can get adapter by calling ((YourAdapter) list.getAdapter())

Comment: for this mainMenulistAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(); line error:The method notifyDataSetInvalidated() is undefined for the type ListView and for this line mainMenulistAdapter.setSelectedValue(position); error:The method setSelectedValue(int) is undefined for the type ListView

Comment: As for the second err you have to write the method like this:
public void setSelectedValue(int selectedValue) {
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
    }
As for the first what ListAdapter do you extend? In my case it is ArrayAdapter and for this one the method is defined.

Comment: So this method is available - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated().
How do get adapter? It should be ((YourAdapterClass) list.getAdapter()).notofyDataSetInvalidated() where YourAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter